# SQLiteOpenHelper.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true) vs SQLiteDatabase.enableWriteAheadLogging()

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I was looking at the JavaDoc for SQLiteOpenHelper and noticed the `setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(boolean)` method.  The SQLiteOpenHelper doc suggest enabling write-ahead logging in a helper's `onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase)` method.

Is there any difference between calling `setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true)` on the helper, compared to calling `enableWriteAheadLogging()` on the database instance that gets passed to `onConfigure()`?  Or is the API just redundant?

**Update**: Looking at the code for [SQLiteDatabase](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java) and [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java), it appears that `SQLiteOpenHelper.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(boolean)` just does some checks (that `enableWriteAheadLogging()` and `disableWriteAheadLogging()` already do) before calling the appropriate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SQLiteOpenHelper setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#128) is mostly just a wrapper for `SQLiteDatabase enableWriteAheadLogging()`:

```
128    public void setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
129        synchronized (this) {
130            if (mEnableWriteAheadLogging != enabled) {
131                if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen() && !mDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
132                    if (enabled) {
133                        mDatabase.enableWriteAheadLogging();
134                    } else {
135                        mDatabase.disableWriteAheadLogging();
136                    }
137                }
138                mEnableWriteAheadLogging = enabled;
139            }
140        }
141    }
```

So yes, it's more or less redundant.

Comment: Ah, just as I was updating the question.  :)  Thanks for confirming that I'm not just missing some nuance.

Comment: What does setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled do exactly?

Comment: @androiddeveloper https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850561/3443247 very nice explaination here.

Comment: @SufiyanAnsari I don't get it.